# ForEach anonymous function, can't return

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I cannot return from a ForEach, here is my code:

```
cards.ForEach(delegate(Card c){
    if (c.GetFaceValue().ToString() == card) {
        return "Your Card has been located";
    }
```

error:

> Cannot convert anonymous method to delegate type '... .Card>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

the following wont work either, as `CheckCard` can only return void:

```
 cards.ForEach(CheckCard);

 public string CheckCard(Card c) {
        if (c.GetFaceValue().ToString() == card) { // card = global 
            return "Your Card has been located";
        }
    }
```

error:

> 'string SharedGamesClasses.Hand.CheckCard(SharedGamesClasses.Card)' has the wrong return type

Comment: to do a foreach on something, you'd expect the delegate to return something that implements IEnumerable. Think of something Like List.FindAll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently trying to return a message from the anonymous function and not your calling code; that won't work as the anonymous function is an `Action<T>`, which can't return anything.

Do you just want to see if any element in `cards` matches `card` and return the message if so?

Use [`.Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) instead of `.ForEach()`:

```
if (cards.Any(c => c.GetFaceValue().ToString() == card))
{
    return "Your Card has been located";
}
```

Comment: i think he needs ALL and not ANY

Comment: thanks! I am a novice at c#, could you please tell me what 'c => c.GetFaceValue().ToString() == card' means? or what that concept is called, so I can look it up.

Comment: Oh, it's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), kind of a shortcut syntax for anonymous delegates. It's the same as `delegate(Card c) { return c.GetFaceValue().ToString() == card; }`.

Answer (score 0):

the ForEach has a void - you cant return a value.

Action is a delegate shortcut for

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(
    T obj
)
```

notice the void here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx

```
public void ForEach(
    Action<T> action
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking on the logic provided, I *suppose* you just gonna terminate iteration as sson as there is `Card` found. Use just a simple `foreach` for this, like for example:

```
string SomeFunc(IEnumerable<Card> cards) 
{
  foreach(Card in cards)
  {
     if(c.GetFaceValue().ToString() == card) {
        return "Your Card has been located";
  }
}
```